# How to stop Xcode from asking me if i want to manually or automatically create schemes?

Tags: xcode

Every time I run `build cfg` Xcode has a pop-up that asks if I want to manually create schemes or if I want it to automatically create schemes. I always choose automatically.

How can I make it so that I does not ask this and just chooses automatically all of the time?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

1- Autocreate scheme is already unticked.

2- When you open Xcode you will have that pop up that asking you for automatically create schemes for some targets.

3- If you tap on Automatically create scheme, The new schemes will be created for some targets.

4- Then to get rid of that pop up again, you need to untick Autocreate scheme again.

This way you wouldn't get that annoying popup in the Xcode launch.

[image]

Comment: The problem is it keeps asking every time you load the project.